# PostSharp 2.0 BadImageFormatException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postsharp

We have an application here which is using postsharp to wrap certain methods within a transaction aspect derived from MethodInterceptionAspect. We use NHibernate 2.0 as an ORM for the application. There is a failure within this block of code,

```
public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
{
    using (TransactionScope transaction = CreateTransactionScope())
    {
        args.Proceed();
        transaction.Complete();
    }
}
```

that results in the following error: System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
This only seems to happen for calls to save, and not delete or get calls.

I was wondering if anyone had encountered anything similar ever?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I've encountered this.  Usually its a 64/32 bit problem.  Check the target in your project settings.

Comment: Target was set to any cpu, which is x64 in my case. I'm fairly certain it's not a 64/32 bit problem since the entire stack is 64 bit.

Comment: + 1. I virtually guarantee this is a x64/32 bit problem.

Answer (score 1):

[Jfar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106227/postsharp-2-0-badimageformatexception/2106351#2106351) is right; That exception means that you either have 64-bit code calling 32-bit code, or vice versa.

I've encountered it before as well.

Here are the steps I used to fix it:

1. Check whether the host OS this is run on is 64-bit.
2. Verify (for our debugging purposes) that the build is *not* targeting "Any-CPU". Force it to target 64 bit if all of the DLLs you're using are 64 bit (see steps #2 and #3), otherwise target 32-bit otherwise.
3. Check your PostSharp download and make sure it's a 64-bit DLL.
4. Check NHibernate 2.0, and make sure you're using the 64-bit version.

You **cannot** mix 32-bit DLLs and a 64-bit application (or vice-versa.

If none of that works, try the steps [outlined here](http://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2009/10/21/force-net-application-to-run-in-32bit-process-on-64bit-os/).

Answer (score 0):

That's odd.
What tells PEVERIFY if you execute it on PostSharp output?